# Is there a Linq to OQL provider?

Tags: linq, oql

I want to convert Linq query to [OQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Query_Language).

Is there a Linq to OQL provider?

Comment: From that link it appears that OQL is a language rather than a particular system. Did you have a particular system in mind? Where's the actual *data*?

Comment: @akramshahda not sure what the point of your edit is?

Comment: @AakashM not sure what is the point of your question .. still the answer can be nothing that is related to you.

Comment: Yes I am looking for querying objects using OQL, My product (data source) understands OQL for querying.

Comment: Any update onto this? What are the factors that will enable to convert LINQ to OQL like ExpressionTrees etc?